# Pass two or more Id column in jQuery data tables as parameter?

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using jQuery data table. I pass one id via `<a href="#">`. Now, i want to pass two or more id in single cell and `<a href="#">`.

**My Code**:

```js
var table = $('table#companyTable').DataTable({

  "sAjaxSource": ResultData, // "/GetcompanyList.json",
  "sAjaxDataProp": "",

  /// sort at column three
  "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],

  "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": null },
    { "mData": "registrationType" },
    { "mData": "companyName" },
    { "mData": "emailId" },
    { "mData": "country" },
    { "mData": "district" },
    { "mData": "registrationDate" },
    { "mData": "companyId" },
    { "mData": "tendererId" },
    {
      "mData": "userId",
      "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
        if(type === 'display'){
          data = '<a href = "/admin/tenderer-reg-details/'+data+'">View</a>';
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
  ],
  // define  first column , is column zero
  "columnDefs": [{
    "searchable": false,
    "orderable": false,
    "targets": 0
  }]
});
```

Now i need to pass `userId`, `companyId`, `tendererId` in one render and `href link`.

**Just like below**

```
data = '<a href = "/admin/tenderer-reg-details/'+userId+'"/"'+companyId+'"/"'+tendererId +'">View</a>';
```

Comment: You can use `row.userId` `row.companyId` `row.tendererId `

Comment: See more about columns defs i think you can create a customize data with the target of column you want show two id's or elemens